# Data storing in plist works in simulaor but not in device

Tags: iphone, plist

I am new to iPhone development. I have created plist such as from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621515/how-to-save-a-value-in-a-plist-file-in-iphone). It works well in simulator but not in device.

I am getting the saved value from the plist and checking for the condition. When I use simulator it works but not in device.

Comment: Need some more info here. Where is the plist located? Added as a resource in Xcode? Created using writeToFile? Also, what do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: This can be closed as _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can't write to a file in the resource folder of an iPhone. It is part of the security system of the phone that prevent malicious code from altering an application after it has been installed.

(2) If you want to save new data to a file you need to write the file to one of the automatically generated folders. Whenever an iPhone app is installed on the device or simulator, the system creates a default set of folders.

(3) You want to write to either the Preferences folder or the Documents folder. If the data concerns the operation of the app, write it to preferences. If it contains user data write to  Documents.

Preferences:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *prefsDirectory = [[sysPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Preferences"];
```

Documents:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *docsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Say you want to read a default preference plist file, make some changes and then save it the preferences folder.

```
NSString *plistPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *defaultPrefs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
//... modify defaultPrefs
NSString *outputFilePath=[prefsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"alteredPrefs.plist"];
[defaultPrefs writeToFile:outputFilePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: I'll have to find a necromancer first. This post is six years old. ;-) Time for some maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fix this!