# How to store values inside Plist and read while runtime in iphone 3.0?

Tags: iphone, plist, store

how to store values inside Plist and read while runtime in iphone 3.0?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623750/data-storing-in-plist-works-in-simulaor-but-not-in-device , this link might help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array or dictionary that contains only "standard" data types like strings, dates, numbers, arrays, and dictionaries, you can save the contents to a .plist file with `-[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` or `-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]`. To read the file, use `-initWithContentsOfFile:`.

Note that the application bundle is not writable on iPhone OS devices so you will have to store the file in your app's Documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be applied to both `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Use this method to make a `NSData` from property list and use `writeToFile` to persist it to disk.

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)plist
                                           format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format
                                 errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString];
```

Use this method to read property list from `NSData`.

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:(NSData *)data
                                 mutabilityOption:(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions)opt
                                           format:(NSPropertyListFormat *)format
                                 errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString];
```

Example:

```
NSPropertyListFormat format = 0;
NSString *errorString = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
        mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
        format:&format errorDescription:&errorString];

if (errorString != nil) {
    NSLog(errorString);
    [errorString release];
}

NSLog(@"got dictionary:%@", dataDict);

errorString = nil;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dataDict
        format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:errorString];

NSLog(@"plist data:%@", data); // convert to NSString to get <plist>
```