# How to take parameters from plist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist, iosdeployment

I am quite new at Objective-C programming, I was asked to develop a framework that could be implemented in IOS apps. This framework has three methods (that take a model object as an argument) that perform API comsumption and return a message (that takes from response). The problem is that I was asked to store the module parameters in plist, and I don´t have a good clue what this means. I been reading about plist and I know they can store serialized objects. But I really don´t understand what it means to be storing all parameters on this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plist is essentially a dictionary (or `NSDictionary`) -- with keys and values -- written to a specific file format that iOS expects.

To write a plist file is easy when you do it from Xcode.  In Xcode 10.3 you can go to "File" -> "New" --> "File..." and select "Property List" from the types of files you see:
[image: File->New->File->PropertyList]

I created a file (as an example) named "SomeFile.plist" and then added a couple keys & values to it:

[image: New Plist File]

Now after you get this file included in your new project, you need to read the keys & values back in.  [Here is a related question that shows you different ways to read the plist / dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921902/how-to-add-and-get-the-values-from-plist-in-ios), such as:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"YourPLIST" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSString *name = [dict stringForKey: @"RaphaelName"];
```

Comment: Note that the root of a plist can also be an array, not just a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much. The releated post mention that he is storing a String object in a plist, then using it when needed, but my question is, what is the usefulness of storing values instead o getting directly from code ?, I am sorry I never seen this aproach before, that is what I am curious about.