# Added files to my Plist - I think I am almost there

Tags: ios, plist, save

In my iOS application I have made a form that should submit data into a plist. I have followed examples from this link amongst other -

> [How to write a data in plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628372/ios-how-to-write-a-data-in-plist)

Now the I think I have done everything right except I am getting one error and it is related to ARC - says Xcode - so I am not sure if the example I used is outdated or if I have just forgotten something.

To clarify - I have the save button with the appropriate -(IBAction) and it is giving no errors so i think I am ok there. the bit that needs tweaking I think is copying the original Data.plist into the document folder which I think I am suppose to achieve with this.

I have pasted the code where the error occurs below. Any help is great and if I can help by posting more code, let me know:-)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


NSString *destPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// If the file doesn't exist in the Documents Folder, copy it.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath];
}

// Load the Property List.
savedReadingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destPath];
}
```

Cheers Jeff

I just noticed I didn't clarify what is giving me the error:

it's this line

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath];
```

and the error is:

> ARC Issue - No visible @interface for 'NSFileManager' declares the selector 'copyItemAtPath:toPath:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used a method that doesn't exist. You just need to change it as

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:nil];
```

Instead of passing `nil` as error, you can also pass your custom `NSError` object. Refer to the [`NSFileManager` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see all allowed methods

Comment: That seemed to get rid of the error thank you - no onto debugging on why I am getting the NSDictionary issue - thank you:-)

Answer (score 2):

NSFileManager doesn contain the method.

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath: toPath:];
```

You should use the following method,

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

Comment: Sorry just to clarify - do you mean swapping the one for the other?

Comment: @jwk82. YES i meant to change it.