# Are there any cases where it's better to use [NSFileManager defaultManager] rather than [[NSFileManager alloc] init]?

Tags: ios

In iOS, I know that there are times when [[NSFileManager alloc] init] is better - particularly when [NSFileManager defaultManager] might not be thread safe. Reference: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/06/12/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-is-not-thread-safe.html

Is it always okay just to use [[NSFileManager alloc] init] instead?

Answer (score 6):

The docs state that `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` is thread safe.

The docs recommend that you should create your own instance if you need to make use of an `NSFileManagerDelegate`.

In the end, creating your own instance should always be fine but unless you need the delegate,  there is no need to create your own instance.

Comment: Doc link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CJBEJDCD

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's always okay to just use `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` instead. `+defaultManager` is really only there for convenience, but as you point out there are thread safety worries with using it. Just make sure you remember to -release your alloc'd `NSFileManager` when you're done with it.