# Store NSString value in plist file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist, uiactionsheet

My question in `UIActionSheet` button add to favourite click and copy `UITableViewCell` in nextview so i am using string value in store dynamic create plist file and first time click cell and open `UIActionSheet` and add to favourite `UIButton` click and copy 1 cell properly but second time add to favourite click and not add 2 item store only 1 new array item so my question in plist file at a time 1 value is add so any answer..`
Store data from plist

```
       -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet   clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
       {

       if (buttonIndex ==2) {

        FavoritesViewController *objfav= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fav"];

         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manuallyData.plist"];

       [arrplist addObject:quote];
        NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: arrplist, nil] forKeys:   [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"icon", nil]]; 
        NSString *error = nil;
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

        if(plistData)
       {
          [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];   
       }
        else
       {
        }

        objfav.arrCopy = arrplist;

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:objfav    animated:YES];
       }
      }

     fetch data from dynamic create plist file in nextview

      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains   (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manuallyData.plist"];

      if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
      {
      plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"manuallyData" ofType:@"plist"];
      }

       NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
       arrCopy = [dict objectForKey:@"icon"];
```

Comment: See the link below...  https://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/  and   http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-13-using-property-lists-plists/

Comment: i am create dynamic plist file

Comment: @SammerKhira i know. but this are the links which are very useful. i have example of Dynamic plist also.

Comment: i have edited your question can you approve it.

Comment: Please see in your answer this [link][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628372/ios-how-to-write-a-data-in-plist