# Can we store login details in plist file - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to store my login details to retrieve back next time. Is it possible to store login related information in plist file? or Do I need to create my own file for that.

thanks

Comment: You can but it should probably be stored in the keychain instead.

Comment: I am new to IOS, What is keychain?

Comment: Have a look at the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, and also you might to take a look at [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [KeyChain Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)

but if you want to use plist. here is a same question.

[How to write data in plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905542/how-to-write-data-in-plist)