# How to read and write data on a plist in Objective-C? (not iOS, regular Cocoa for OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to learn how to read and write data from a plist file, using cocoa on OS X.

I've look around but I see a lot of examples for iOS; and I assume that even if the 2 cocoa frameworks are about the same, you do it in a different way on OS X, compared to iOS.

Is there any place where I can get a tutorial about how to read and write data from/to a plist in Cocoa?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write data in plist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905542/how-to-write-data-in-plist)

Comment: @newbiez Please accept my answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise it will still show up in the 'unanswered questions'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way (minus getting the actual file, but as far as I understand that's not the question being asked).

If you want to read a plist file you use `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:]` or `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]` or the respective methods on `NSDictionary`

If you are writing to a plist you just use `[NSArray/NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]`

edited to add info from Catfish_Man's comment:

The above works for plists where the root object is either an array or a dictionary. For other root objects have a look at [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You can also use NSPropertyListSerialization for more fine-grained control, and the ability to use other plist types than the two collections.

Comment: Didn't know about NSPropertyListSerialization. I have only ever used plists with arrays or dictionaries as root objects. I'll update my answer.